# Componente WebView no Ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic, webview

Existe algum componente ou `plugin` do `Ionic` que se assemelhe com o `WebView` do `Android`?

Precisa carregar uma página da web no aplicativo.

Comment: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/ veja se isso ajuda.